# GoogleSignIn DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN error

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin

So i'm trying to implement google signIn for my app. I have my oAuth clients ID for the debug version, the release and everything. I also implemented Firebase.

Well, everything works fine if i use DEFAULT_SIGN_IN in the Builder, but if i change that for DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN, the intent does nothing (attempts to pop but it just crashes) and i get "signInResult:failed code=12501". I believe this is because the intent gives no account since it doesn't load properly.

```
 gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

//OnClick for the sign in
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

I also tried providing the requestIdToken with my debug key, instead of the web. Nothing happens either.

I checked the SHA-1, the application_ID, if the API is allowed to connect with Google Play Games... I don't know if i'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

i know i m a bit late but if you want to use DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN then you had to replace requestIdToken with requestServerAuthCode and in place of requestEmail you can use requestProfile

Answer (score 0):

I use meta-data in my AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

and it's resolve problem with 12501 error

Comment: so you can get this data from google play games console